# Merge statement for stocks using three tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

Here is the SQL Query:

```
MERGE  tblProductsSold

USING tblOrders on tblOrders.OrderID = tblProductsSold.txtOrderID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 

Insert ( txtOrderID, txtOrderdate, txtPartno, txtQty)  
values 
(SELECT tblItemsOnOrder.txtOrderID, 
 tblOrders.txtDateTime, 
 tblItemsOnOrder.txtPartNO, 
 tblItemsOnOrder.txtQTY
FROM tblOrders  INNER JOIN tblItemsOnOrder 
ON tblOrders.OrderID = tblItemsOnOrder.txtOrderID
WHERE tblOrders.txtIsConfirmed = '1'
)

OUTPUT $action ;
```

Desired Result: need to import orders with `Products` that are not already in the `tblProductsSold` table

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot approach it like you are doing it right now.

The `MERGE` statement merges two tables - the two tables you define in the header - the **source** table and the **target** table.

Right now, you're using `tblOrders` as your source, and `tblProducts` as your target. That alone seems odd - you're trying to merge **orders** into **products**? Doesn't seem very fitting...

Once you've defined your source and target table - you stat comparing which rows from the source are present in the target (or not). If a given row from your source is not present in the target - then you can insert its values into the target table.

But that **only** works for **direct column values** from the source table! You cannot go out and do subqueries into other tables as you're trying to do!

So I believe what you **really** should do is this:

- as your **source** - have a view that lists the products found in your orders - the **products** (not the orders per se)
- then compare your `Products` table to this view - if your orders happen to have any products that aren't present in the base `Products` table - insert them.

So you'd need something like:

```
MERGE  tblProductsSold AS Target
USING (SELECT tblItemsOnOrder.txtOrderID, tblOrders.txtDateTime, 
              tblItemsOnOrder.txtPartNO, tblItemsOnOrder.txtQty
       FROM tblOrders  
       INNER JOIN tblItemsOnOrder ON tblOrders.OrderID = tblItemsOnOrder.txtOrderID
       WHERE tblOrders.txtIsConfirmed = '1') AS Source
   ON Source.OrderID = Target.txtOrderID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (txtOrderID, txtOrderdate, txtPartno, txtQty)  
    VALUES (Source.OrderID, Source.txtDateTime, Source.txtPartNo, Source.txtQty)

OUTPUT $action ;
```

Comment: Thank you I have done something smiliar

and managed to get the results done